# Disabling a button when a list item isn't selected in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have the following piece of code to create a JList:

```
rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
final JList list = new JList(nameData);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 80));
listScroller.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
rightPanel.add(listScroller);
```

And I have this code for a `listSelectionListener()` to disable a button, when an item in the list isn't selected:

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
            if (list.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
                //No selection.
                deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                //Selection.
                deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(true);
                index = list.getSelectedIndex();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But whether an item in the list is selected or not, the state for the button doesn't change. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `deleteConfirmButton` `disable-enable` logic is not correct. At first you need to `disable`. At the selection of list you should `enable` and at the click on `deleteConfirmButton` button you shoudl again `disable`. Read the comment of following code.

```
    final JButton deleteConfirmButton = new JButton("Kustuta");
    deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(false); //Disable here
```

---

```
    deleteConfirmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(false);//Disable here            
    }
   });
```

---

```
  list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
           deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(true);//Enable here
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, now you made it clear for me and the following changes to the code solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `deleteConfirmButton` is inside a `JPanel` named rightPanel, call the `repaint` and `revalidate` methods to paint the button again.

```
if (list.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
            //No selection.
      deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(false);
} else {
      //Selection.
      deleteConfirmButton.setEnabled(true);
      index = list.getSelectedIndex();
}
rightPanel.repaint();
rightPanel.revalidate();
```

Comment: Adding those into the if in ListSelectionListener() doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The problem still stays.